# python copy, копирование классов

Tags: python, классы, copy

Когда выполняю код:

```
import copy


class LeafParameters:
    FLOW_TYPE = 'flow type: '

temp = copy.deepcopy(LeafParameters)
temp.FLOW_TYPE = '123'


print(LeafParameters.FLOW_TYPE)
print(temp.FLOW_TYPE)
```

имею следующий вывод:

```
123
123
```

А хотелось бы что бы оригинал `LeafParameters` продолжал иметь `FLOW_TYPE = 'flow type: '`

Comment: Вам просто нужно понять разницу между классами и экземплярами классов )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может я чего-то не понял, но зачем копировать?

```
class LeafParameters:
    FLOW_TYPE = 'flow type: '

temp = LeafParameters()
temp1= LeafParameters()
temp.FLOW_TYPE = '123'

print(temp1.FLOW_TYPE)
print(LeafParameters.FLOW_TYPE)
print(temp.FLOW_TYPE)
```

---

```
flow type: 
flow type: 
123
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сработало, я почему то думал что только с копией будет работать

Answer (score 5):

При попытке копировать класс с помощью `deepcopy` или просто `copy` возвращается сам же класс:

```
import copy


class LeafParameters:
    FLOW_TYPE = 'flow type: '


temp = copy.deepcopy(LeafParameters)

print(id(LeafParameters))
print(id(temp))
print(temp is LeafParameters)
```

Пример вывода:

```
94618641916496
94618641916496
True
```

id (адрес) один и тот же, значит объект (класс - тоже объект) один и тот же. Результат `True` сравнения через `is` также показывает, что это один и тот же объект.

Соответствующий кусок [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html):

> This module does not copy types like module, method, stack trace, stack frame, file, socket, window, or any similar types. ***It does “copy” functions and classes (shallow and deeply), by returning the original object unchanged***; this is compatible with the way these are treated by the pickle module.

Т.е. буквально, при попытке копировать (поверхностно или глубоко) функцию или класс будет возвращен исходный объект без изменений.

Если создавать объекты класса и копировать их, все будет работать как и ожидалось:

```
import copy


class LeafParameters:
    FLOW_TYPE = 'flow type: '


ob = LeafParameters()
temp = copy.deepcopy(ob)

temp.FLOW_TYPE = '123'

print(ob.FLOW_TYPE)
print(LeafParameters.FLOW_TYPE)
print(temp.FLOW_TYPE)
```

Вывод:

```
flow type: 
flow type: 
123
```